# C# RegEx not working like it should when using min and max operators

Tags: c#, regex

so im working on a little piece of code that has to regex some stuff.
in general its working except one regex which returns way to much stuff on the first match but works as intended on every other match afterwards.

I build the regex using regex101.com and it looks like this:

```
>(?<ev>[0-9]{1,3}\s(HP|Atk|Def|SpD|SpA|Spe))<
```

The code in c# looks like this:

```
pattern = ">(?<ev>^[0-9]+${1,3}\\s(HP|Atk|Def|SpD|SpA|Spe))<";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(html, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["ev"].Captures[0].Value);
}
```

The html im regexing is this: http://pokedex.project-sato.net/files/localfile.html

Example that i also tested and doesnt work: http://pastebin.com/6H0QnFBP

Output in the console is empty.

EDIT:

The output should look like:

```
4 Def
252 SpA
252 Spe
```

Comment: You should say us what you want filter with this regex

Comment: this regex for example `<ul .*? class=\"NatureList\".*?>.*?<abbr .*?title=\".*?\".*?>(?<nature>.*?)<\\/abbr>.*?` works without any problems and the angled brackets arent escaped

Comment: Please include the text you're matching *in the question* - ideally in the form of a [mcve] that we can copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: Is `pattern = ">(?<ev>^[` supposed to have the `^`?

Comment: Done. I just extracted the part that isnt working despite running the regex against the whole html file. It produces the same result tho.

Comment: I'm a bit confused reading your regex. I see no multi-line option, but you include characters before "^" and after "$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adjusting your first matching group as you currently have `[0-9]+{1,3}` which would match one or more digits, three times.

It's likely that you are want 1-3 digits along with one of your properties (i.e. `HP`,`Atk`, etc.) which would use the following expression :

```
// This will match 1-3 digits followed by one of your properties
pattern = ">(?<ev>\d{1,3}\\s(HP|Atk|Def|SpD|SpA|Spe))\<");
```

This also removes the beginning and constraints of `^` and `$` as these values could be likely found throughout your input so you don't want to restrict it to a single line.

**Example**

[image]

You can [see an example of this that uses a snippet of your targeted HTML file as input here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IxR4an).

Comment: thx worked for me. i guess you really learn something new every day